# How to trigger validation in formik after rendering?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have one question with formik. Basically, I will have a table which list all the Id of the forms which have errors. When user click on the Id of a form, it will show up the form itself. The requirement is the errors should be showing also when the form is rendered. Does anyone know how to do that with Formik ? Also, if user edit the field the field validation should works as normal.

I put the codesandbox link here. https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-brattain-yyls2. Basically I want that when the form show up I should see the errors, not just when user move away from the field or changing it. Thank you.

```
import { Formik, Field, Form } from "formik";
import { TextField } from "formik-material-ui";

class Post0 extends React.Component {
   validateEmptyName(value) {
      if (!value) {
        return "Invalid Name";
      }
   }

 render() {
  return (
  <div>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: "",
        animal: ""
      }}
      onSubmit={values => {
        this.props.nextStep(values);
      }}
      render={({ values, isSubmitting }) => (
        <Form>
          <Field
            name="email"
            type="email"
            value={values.email}
            component={TextField}
            variant="outlined"
            validate={this.validateEmptyName}
          />
          <Field
            name="animal"
            value={values.animal}
            component={TextField}
            variant="outlined"
          />

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
```

}
}

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want to validate a form that you know will be empty? It may make more sense, be easier to implement and more visually appealing to simply indicate that the field is required.

Comment: Hi @RutherfordWonkington, Sorry for the confusion, this is just an example. The initialStates may not be empty. For example, 'email' = '' and 'animal'='cat'. But when i show the form, i would like to see the errors shown up there. The use case here is there is a table with the ID of the forms that has validation errors. When user click on an ID, the form with validation errors should show up. Thanks

Comment: Ah.  It might be difficult with the structure you have now.  FormikProps has a ```validateForm``` method, but calling it within the child render function will trigger an infinite loop. Also, since you're using library components as inputs which accept the Formik props, you'll need to make sure that the fields will display the validation messages without being touched first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made a [basic demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-perlman-oswmv) version using a custom input component.  Formik has no built-in options to do this so unfortunately you need to create your own field components to integrate with Formik's props and bypass the logic that won't show validations if the form's not touched.

```
const Input = ({ field, form }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    form.validateForm();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        style={{
          border: form.errors[field.name] ? "1px solid red" : "1px solid #ccc"
        }}
        name={field.name}
        value={field.value}
        onChange={field.onChange}
      />
      {form.errors[field.name] && (
        <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{form.errors[field.name]}</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And then pass this as the `component` prop on your `<Field/>`.

Formik does provide an `isInitialValid` prop which you could set to `false` on the main Formik component, but again the library TextFields you're using won't display anything without the `touched` prop.

Answer (score 9):

**2021 update:**

Use `validateOnMount` prop:

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#validateonmount-boolean

Comment: No, it doesn't work if you use `enableRenitialize', which most people do: https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/3051

Answer (score 4):

`validateOnMount` works if you also add `initialTouched`, but it has limitation (...or better say bug) when it shows validation issues after submit which doesn't lead to different view or component.

I have found pretty elegant workaround which works as expected.

```
const formikRef = React.useRef(null);
React.useEffect(() => formikRef.current.validateForm(), []);

return (
    <Formik
        innerRef={formikRef}
        initialValues={props.customer}
        initialTouched={mapObject(props.customer, true)}
        onSubmit={values => {
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use isInitialValid or initialErrors to valid initial values.
check their official docs [here](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik).

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this using Yup's [`validateAtSync` function](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedvalidatesyncatpath-string-value-any-options-object-any) while populating the initial values of my form from the querystring.

```html
function generateInitialValues(tabs: TabType[], router: any, validationSchema: any) {
  const initialValues: { [key: string]: number | string }  = {};
  _.forEach(tabs, (tab: TabType) => {
    _.forEach(tab.formFields, (f: FormField) => {
      let isFieldValid;
      try {
        // https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedvalidatesyncatpath-string-value-any-options-object-any
        console.log('validation schema validateAt: ', validationSchema.validateSyncAt(f.id, router.query[f.id]));
        isFieldValid = validationSchema.validateSyncAt(f.id, router.query[f.id]);
      } catch (e) {
        // do nothing on purpose to stop exception from being thrown
        // TODO: Consider doing something here, such as recording a metric
      }

      initialValues[f.id] = isFieldValid ? router.query[f.id] : f.defaultValue;
    })
  });
  return initialValues;
}
```