# Formik - Trigger validation from very first keypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

On the following StackBlitz I have a very simple form validation. The validation is done when the user clicks the submit button.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-formik-yup-example-uhdg-83teyn?file=Registration.js

```
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

export default () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: '',
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .required('Email is required.')
          .email('Email is invalid.'),
      })}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        console.log(values);
        setSubmitting(false);
      }}
      enableReinitialize
    >
      {({ setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form>
          <div>
            <Field
              type="text"
              name="email"
              onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                console.log(value);
                setFieldValue('email', value);
              }}
            />
            <ErrorMessage name="email">
              {(error) => <div style={{ color: '#f00' }}>{error}</div>}
            </ErrorMessage>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

**What I need is:** Trigger the validation from the very first keypress (please notice that I'm not interested in validate it when the component is mounted, but just after the first keypress).

**In other words:** any keypress on any input inside the Formik should trigger the validation only for that specific input (not for others). It would be like the same effect like typing something in that input and then hitting Enter (because when hitting Enter we trigger the validation). But I want that to happen without hitting Enter.

Any idea on how to do that in a proper way?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger validation in formik after rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294208/how-to-trigger-validation-in-formik-after-rendering)

Comment: unfortunately not. What I want is to trigger the validation from the very first keypress. Please notice that I'm not interested in validate it when the component is mounted, but just after the first keypress.

Comment: Any keypress within the whole page? Or is it happening on the first keypress in some special input?

Comment: any keypress on any input inside the Formik should trigger the validation only for that specific input (not for others). It would be like the same effect like typing something on that input and then hitting Enter (because when hitting Enter we trigger the validation). But I want that to happen without hitting Enter.

Comment: Has this been answered?
If so could you post the solution here.

Comment: @Jith I don't think so, do you have any suggestion?
I'm faced with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can render Field with a child component such as `<input>` and handle its onKeyDown event. Rendering it this way gives you access to Formik's props which you can use to trigger validation.

```
         <Field name="email">
          {({ field, form }) => (
            <input
              onKeyDown={() => form.setFieldTouched('email')}
              {...field}
              id="email"
            />
          )}
        </Field>
        <ErrorMessage name="email">
          {(error) => <div style={{ color: '#f00' }}>{error}</div>}
        </ErrorMessage>
```